# Why won't the 'top' property animate the transistion?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to get it so that when you hover over the box the '^' will animate upwards. Currently it gets to the right position on the over state but it does not apply the css transistion.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9f9fyaj2/

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="scrollToTop">
        <i>^</i>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: #7A7A7A;
}
.scrollToTop{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.scrollToTop i{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: top .02s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top .02s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: top .02s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top .02s ease-out;
    transition: top .02s ease-out;
}

.scrollToTop:hover i{
    top:-20px;
}

.scrollToTop:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: The time duration is very small mate. If you make it to even `2s` you will notice the transition :)

Comment: @Harry is right .. here is a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9f9fyaj2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your transition is working well and good.
Just increase the time given for the transition.

Like This:

```
.scrollToTop i{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            -webkit-transition: top .5s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: top .5s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: top .5s ease-out;
            -o-transition: top .5s ease-out;
            transition: top .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Also changed your given fiddle. Take a look.